# Can I setup an auto-response for all friend requests?

Tags: facebook

I accidentally created two Facebook accounts.  I want to migrate to one account only, but continuously get friend requests on the account I don't want to use.

If I could configure an auto-response for all friend requests, telling the requestor to please redirect their request to the other account, I could safely begin ignoring the old one.

Answer (score 4):

No you cannot set up an auto-response.

Just close the account by reporting the profile, that way new friends will only see one account when searching.

[image: Close Account]

Comment: Thanks!  Now I know I can stop trying to figure out how to setup an auto-response, and I hadn't considered that people would just find the right account if I closed the one I don't one.